# Changing axes units

Tags: plotting

I have plotted a graph in mathematica, where the x axis is in seconds. I want to scale the axis so it displays years instead.

My plotting function is as follows:

```
Plot[sol1[t], {t, 0, 1 * 10^(16)},
   PlotRange -> All
   FrameLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Velocity (ms-1)"},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]}]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach is to change the option value for  `FrameLabel` and use `FrameTicks` with custom ticks:

```
sol[t_] := 1 + Sinc[10^-15   Pi t];

Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10^16}, 
   Frame -> True,  ImageSize -> Large, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Velocity (ms-1)"}]
```

[image]

```
year = 60 60 24 365;

fticks = {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0,  1/year}], Automatic}};


Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10^16}, 
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Time (year)", "Velocity (ms-1)"}, 
   FrameTicks -> fticks]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a documentation page explaining how Charting`FindTicks works, for example if I want to scale the y axis? I'm very new to Mathematica and not had much luck finding it.

Comment: @testing09, the (undocumented)  function ``Charting`FindTicks[{a, b}, {c, d}][min, max]`` generates the major and minor ticks based on the automatically computed minimum and maximum of the values on the axis using the scaling parameters `{a, b}`, {`c, d}` for computing the labels for major ticks. I think the way it works is  ...

Comment: ... as follows: First, [FindDivisions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html) is used with inputs `min`, `max`  and, some hard-coded parameter for the number of major and minor ticks ticks  (which, I guess,  is `{6,6}`) to compute major and minor ticks; then, for major tick `t`, `Rescale[t, {a,b}, {c,d}]`  is used to compute the tick label for `t`.

Answer (score 2):

For illustration purposes let `sol1` be

```
sol1[t_] = Exp[-3*^-16 t];
```

The original plot

```
Plot[sol1[t], {t, 0, 1*10^(16)}, PlotRange -> All,
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Velocity (ms-1)"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]},
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

The average number of seconds in a year

```
yr = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"]

(* 31536000 *)
```

The rescaled plot

```
Plot[sol1[t*yr], {t, 0, 10^16/yr},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time (yr)", "Velocity (ms-1)"},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]},
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]